# Eclipse code template with imports

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse neon and added the following code template which sets the mockito JUnit runner and the necessary imports:

```
${:import(org.junit.runner.RunWith,org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner)}
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
```

The result is

```
import 
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)t.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;
```

The same template works just fine in Eclipse Kepler. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just three years and ten months later.

I just add some single quotes to the imports (and change one deprecated):

```
${:import('org.junit.runner.RunWith','org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner')}
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
```

And that's all.

Cheers.